# Função javascript

Tags: javascript

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]Eu estou  preciso Criar uma função dobroDoProximo() que recebe um parâmetro e nos retorna duas vezes mais que o próximo, ou seja, parâmetro + 1.
então eu fiz :

```
function dobroDoProximo (numero1, numero2) {
   var numero1 * numero2 ;
   return  dobroDoProximo +1;
}
```

mas não ta indo, açguém pode ajudar por favor ?

Comment: Coloque algum exemplo da saída que você deseja, está muito confuso o texto.

Comment: eu adicionei uma imagem, vê se ajuda

Comment: Eu só acho ruim que as soluções que as pessoas dão sempre envolvem variáveis desnecessárias e solução mais complexa do que deveria, às vezes por falta de matemática, e que aí alguns dizem ser mais legível escrever mais código (escrever código desnecessário nunca foi legível, mas agora é a desculpa preferida).

Comment: Se fosse Black Friday seria `metadeDoDobro()`

Answer (score 4):

### Sem complicar:

Como ninguem postou o código mais básico, aqui vai:

```
function dobroDoProximo(atual){
   return (atual+1)*2;
}
```

### Demonstração:

```js
function dobroDoProximo(atual){
   return (atual+1)*2;
}


console.log(dobroDoProximo(4));   // tem que ser 10
console.log(dobroDoProximo(0));   // tem que ser 2
console.log(dobroDoProximo(417)); // tem que ser 836
```

Comment: Daria para escrever de outras maneiras, mas perderia a semântica. Ex: `return atual*2+2;` que dá o mesmo resultado mas atrapalha a legibilidade. Assim como sair pondo variável a toa também me incomoda nesse caso, pois a operação é simples demais a ponto dos parênteses garantirem a legibilidade e interpretação da intenção.

Answer (score 2):

Você precisa criar uma variável (var) que soma o parametro próximo+1 e dps retornar a variável multiplicando por 2. Pelos menos funcionol assim pra mim, já que eu tenho a leve impressão dessa plataforma ter alguns bugs com o console, baseando-se em eu voltar pra um exercício, que estava dando correto, modifica-lo e retornar ao "correto" e dar erro, mesmo reiniciando o console. ¯_(ツ)_/¯

```
function dobroDoProximo(numero1){
   var soma = numero1+1;
   return soma*2;
}
```

Comment: Funcionou \o/  , eu jamais imaginei que fosse dessa forma pq eu estava pensando que tinha que pegar a variavel com a multiplicação e somar +1 . Obrigado!!

Comment: Não precisa usar variáveis intermediárias, são ciclos de processamento e alocação de memória que podem ser evitados nesse caso.

Answer (score 1):

Algumas coisas nao precisa enfeitar demais. Simples e objetivo.

```
function dobroDoProximo(numero1){

   return numero1 * 2 + 2
}
```

Comment: Para formatar as perguntas e respostas use [MarkDown](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Answer (score -2):

Precisa atribuir o valor da multiplicação dos números em outra variável.

```js
function dobroDoProximo (numero1, numero2) {
   var dobro = numero1 * numero2 ;
   return  dobro +1;
}
```

Acredito que o enunciado do problema está pedindo uma função que multiplique o número por 2 e some mais um nesse valor. Então a função seria algo parecido com isso:

```js
function dobroDoProximo(proximo) {
 var dobro = 2 * proximo;
 return dobro + 1;
}
```

Comment: Exatamente isso --->     "Acredito que o enunciado do problema está pedindo uma função que multiplique o número por 2 e some mais um"   --- mas não funcionou como você fez

Comment: Não fui eu que negativei mas estou quase para negativar. Não precisa usar variáveis intermediárias, são ciclos de processamento e alocação de memória que podem ser evitados nesse caso.

Comment: @AugustoVasques tambem nao fui eu, mas tem uma inversão na ordem das operações. Ele está fazendo o "proximo do dobro" e não o "dobro do próximo".

Comment: Agora eu negativei, a resposta além de sugerir como certo um conceito desnecessário está equivocada.